# It gives me error "conflicting typer for 'mysqrt'"

Tags: c, xcode

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float mysqrt (float x)

{

    float y;
    x=x-1;
    y= 1+(x/2)-(pow(x,2)/2)+(pow(x,3)/8)-(5*pow(x,4)/128);


    return y;

}

int main()

{

    printf("%f",mysqrt(5));
}
```

I searched older answer in this website and tried to use them but still I cant figure out why it doesnt work

Comment: Cannot duplicate: http://ideone.com/hnikmQ  A runtime error shows up, but not a compile error.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that the function call in `main()` does not appear **before** the definition of `mysqrt()`?

Comment: I tried both of them. When mysqrt is after the main and when it is before like this one.They both didnt work. And I use XCODE but I also tried it in my university's website compile for C and it didnt work in it either.

Comment: The only other explanation I can come up with is that there is _another_ `mysqrt` (with a different type) in some other module.

Comment: @Can - Please reduce your program down to this: http://ideone.com/t7eyHn  If this doesn't compile, then you have a broken compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the code you have posted is quite accurate.

You are probably calling `mysqrt()` *before* you have provided a declaration of the function. In old versions of the C standard (C89), this was allowed and the function would be given an implicit declaration of:

```
int mysqrt();
```

That is, a function taking an unknown number of non-variadic parameters, and returning int. This clearly contradicts the actual definition of the function.

In more recent versions of the standard (C99/C11), the compiler is required to produce a diagnostic message if you try to call a function that has not been declared.

You should change your code so that the function definition appears *before* the function call, **or** provide a function declaration *before* the function call. Eg:

```
float mysqrt (float);

int main()
{
  printf("%f",mysqrt(5));
}

float mysqrt (float x)
{
  /* Function body */
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked. I understood now. Its exactly true I think, it needed to declared first then be used. Thank you very much.